# ConversionService bean vs regular converter bean for convert Object

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to convert Entity to another object for response (ex: `ActionEntity` to `ActionResponse`).

In Spring we can create a bean like this:

```
@Component
public class EntityToResponseConverter implements Converter<ActionEntity,
ActionResponse>{
    @Override
    public RequestResponse convert(ActionEntity entity) {
        ActionResponse response = new ActionResponse();
        response.setId(entity.getId());
        response.setOrigId(entity.getOrigId());       
        return response;
    }
}
```

And then I autowire a ConversionService to use.

Another way I can create new bean like this:

```
@Component
public class EntityToResponseConverter {

    public ActionResponse convert(ActionEntity entity) {
        ActionResponse response = new ActionResponse();
        response.setId(entity.getId());
        response.setOrigId(entity.getOrigId());       
        return response;
    }
}
```

And then I autowire this bean to use.
When we should implement Converter instead of create a regular bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Converter` is an interface which you can used for automatically converting:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new YourCustomConverter());
    }
}
```

When converters registered, Spring will automatically convert request data for your controller if the data type match.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful, any documents link can I read about it?

Comment: You can read it here [Spring Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#core-convert)